# Background Image Not Appearing in Asp.Net Site Using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have two installations of Visual Studio, one is 2010 Ultimate, and the other is 2012 Ultimate. There are two pages in my site which display a background image associated with the page on `PageLoad`.  This is the code which pulls the image from the directory and displays it as the background image:

```
public partial class TechCall : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    script.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    script.Append("document.body.style.background = \"url('/Cyber7th/Images/CPUBack2nd.jpg')\";");
    script.Append("document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';");
    script.Append("</script>");

    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "changeBackground", script.ToString());
}    
}
```

The other page has the same code, but just references a different image, and is this:

```
public partial class Build_It : System.Web.UI.Page
```

EDIT: Here is what the page should look like:

[image]

Now in Visual Studio 2010 this works just fine... when viewed in a browser (Firefox here), the background image shows up with no problem, and all the functionality is there.

However, with the project in Visual Studio 2012, viewing the page using this same code and in the same browser for testing, I get this:

[image]

Viewing the page in VS 2012 in the browser does not show the background image - there is a **white space** instead of the background image. Again, Firefox is being used, but the it happens no matter which one I use in 2012 (IE, Chrome, and Internal Browser). VS 2010 shows the background images in all browsers.  So that is the output that I should be seeing, which is the background images.

Again, this has to be something with VS 2012, as I am not having this issue with 2010. Maybe, if I would have built this from ground up in VS 2012 instead of attempting to port the solution, perhaps I would not have this issue? Hopefully this helps to explain my issue a bit clearer.

Comment: Also, if it helps to know, both of these pages happen to contain **.ascx controls** within the page. All other pages are the usual **.aspx pages**.

Comment: Can you give us a little more information as to what is actually being output.  Is your script being created on the page, is it running, have your images come across when you migrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this on `Page_Load` to dynamically change the image:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/SampleBackground.png";
```

Create a folder `Images` in your server and add your background image to it. Then you can refer it with the above code. This is not using javascript but plain c#.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have this type of structure for my Images directory, which I use to populate images next to my `RadioButtonList` controls; thus my issue is not in this area of the code.